# How to render a SceneKit shader at a lower resolution?

Tags: ios, swift, shader, scenekit, metal

I'm adding some visual elements to my app with [SceneKit shader modifiers](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnshadable) like this:

```swift
// A SceneKit scene with orthographic projection

let shaderBundle = Bundle(for: Self.self)
let shaderUrl = shaderBundle.url(forResource: "MyShader.frag", withExtension: nil)!
let shaderString = try! String(contentsOf: shaderUrl)

let plane = SCNPlane(width: 512, height: 512)  // 1024x1024 pixels on devices with x2 screen resolution
plane.firstMaterial!.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.fragment: shaderString]

let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: plane)
rootNode.addChildNode(planeNode)
```

The problem is slow performance because SceneKit is painstakingly rendering every single pixel of the plane that's screening the shader. How do I decrease the resolution of the shader keeping the plain's size unchanged?

I've already tried making `plane` smaller and using an enlarging scale transformation on `planeNode` but fruitless, the rendition of the shader remained as highly detailed as before.

Using `plane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contentsTransform` didn't help either (or maybe I was doing it wrong).

I know I could make the global `SCNView` smaller and then apply an affine scale transform if that shader was the only node in the scene but it's not, there are other nodes (that aren't shaders) in the same scene and I'd prefer to avoid altering their appearance in any way.

Comment: Are you using a texture on the material? The way I understand it a fragment shader is executed per "fragment", and a fragment would be a pixel, so if you set a 512x512 texture it might be executed only on those pixels.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Setting `plane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents` to a 16x16 `UIImage` didn't make any difference (and I can see the low res texture just fine if I disable the shader modifier).

Comment: @DesmondHume what kind of shader do you use?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 A fragment shader heavy on computations

Comment: @DesmondHume can you post your shader code here?

Comment: @0xBFE1A8 The are no issues with the shader itself. For experimenting you could use any shader that gives a sense of a resolution (like checkers or an outlined circle).

Comment: Have you tried using a program instead of a shader modifier? The downside is that you might have to do the whole lighting in your shader, but I think shader modifiers are supposed to be quick programs that make small adjustments.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Haven't tried a program because of a) code overhead b) I'd still be wondering how to render a shader at a lower resolution. Shader modifiers are pretty much capable of rendering anything what a typical buffer-less shader can render on e.g. Shadertoy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like I managed to solve it using a sort of "render to texture" approach by nesting a SceneKit scene inside a SpriteKit scene being displayed by the top level SceneKit scene.

Going into more detail, the following subclass of `SCNNode` is placing a downscaled shader plane within a SpriteKit's `SK3DNode`, then taking that `SK3DNode` and putting it inside a SpriteKit scene as a SceneKit's `SKScene`, and then using that `SKScene` as the diffuse contents of an upscaled plane put inside the top level SceneKit scene.

Strangely, for keeping the native resolution I need to use `scaleFactor*2`, so for halving the rendering resolution (normally scale factor 0.5) I actually need to use `scaleFactor = 1`.

If anyone happens to know the reason for this strange behavior or a workaround for it, please let me know in a comment.

```swift
import Foundation
import SceneKit
import SpriteKit

class ScaledResolutionFragmentShaderModifierPlaneNode: SCNNode {

    private static let nestedSCNSceneFrustumLength: CGFloat = 8

    // For shader parameter input
    let shaderPlaneMaterial: SCNMaterial

    // shaderModifier: the shader
    // planeSize: the size of the shader on the screen
    // scaleFactor: the scale to be used for the shader's rendering resolution; the lower, the faster
    init(shaderModifier: String, planeSize: CGSize, scaleFactor: CGFloat) {
        let scaledSize = CGSize(width: planeSize.width*scaleFactor, height: planeSize.height*scaleFactor)

        // Nested SceneKit scene with orthographic projection
        let nestedSCNScene = SCNScene()
        let camera = SCNCamera()
        camera.zFar = Double(Self.nestedSCNSceneFrustumLength)
        camera.usesOrthographicProjection = true
        camera.orthographicScale = Double(scaledSize.height/2)
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = camera
        cameraNode.simdPosition = simd_float3(x: 0, y: 0, z: Float(Self.nestedSCNSceneFrustumLength/2))
        nestedSCNScene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)
        let shaderPlane = SCNPlane(width: scaledSize.width, height: scaledSize.height)
        shaderPlaneMaterial = shaderPlane.firstMaterial!
        shaderPlaneMaterial.shaderModifiers = [SCNShaderModifierEntryPoint.fragment: shaderModifier]
        let shaderPlaneNode = SCNNode(geometry: shaderPlane)
        nestedSCNScene.rootNode.addChildNode(shaderPlaneNode)

        // Intermediary SpriteKit scene
        let nestedSCNSceneSKNode = SK3DNode(viewportSize: scaledSize)
        nestedSCNSceneSKNode.scnScene = nestedSCNScene
        nestedSCNSceneSKNode.position = CGPoint(x: scaledSize.width/2, y: scaledSize.height/2)
        nestedSCNSceneSKNode.isPlaying = true
        let intermediarySKScene = SKScene(size: scaledSize)
        intermediarySKScene.backgroundColor = .clear
        intermediarySKScene.addChild(nestedSCNSceneSKNode)
        let intermediarySKScenePlane = SCNPlane(width: scaledSize.width, height: scaledSize.height)
        intermediarySKScenePlane.firstMaterial!.diffuse.contents = intermediarySKScene
        let intermediarySKScenePlaneNode = SCNNode(geometry: intermediarySKScenePlane)
        let invScaleFactor = 1/Float(scaleFactor)
        intermediarySKScenePlaneNode.simdScale = simd_float3(x: invScaleFactor, y: invScaleFactor, z: 1)

        super.init()

        addChildNode(intermediarySKScenePlaneNode)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In general, without a fairly new GPU feature called [variable rasterization rate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlrenderpassdescriptor/rendering_at_different_rasterization_rates) in Metal or [variable rate shading](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/directx/variable-rate-shading-a-scalpel-in-a-world-of-sledgehammers/) elsewhere, you can’t make one object in a scene run its fragment shader at a different resolution than the rest of the scene.

For this case, depending on what your setup is, you might be able to use [SCNTechnique](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scntechnique) to render the plane in a separate pass at a different resolution, then composite that back into your scene, in the same way some game engines [render particles at a lower resolution](https://developer.nvidia.com/gpugems/gpugems3/part-iv-image-effects/chapter-23-high-speed-screen-particles) to save on fill rate. Here’s an example.

First, you’ll need a Metal file in your project (if you already have one, just add to it), containing the following:

```
#include <SceneKit/scn_metal>

struct QuadVertexIn {
    float3 position [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticPosition) ]];
    float2 uv [[ attribute(SCNVertexSemanticTexcoord0) ]];
};

struct QuadVertexOut {
    float4 position [[ position ]];
    float2 uv;
};

vertex QuadVertexOut quadVertex(QuadVertexIn v [[ stage_in ]]) {
    QuadVertexOut o;
    o.position = float4(v.position.x, -v.position.y, 1, 1);
    o.uv = v.uv;
    return o;
}

constexpr sampler compositingSampler(coord::normalized, address::clamp_to_edge, filter::linear);

fragment half4 compositeFragment(QuadVertexOut v [[ stage_in ]], texture2d<half, access::sample> compositeInput [[ texture(0) ]]) {
    return compositeInput.sample(compositingSampler, v.uv);
}
```

Then, in your SceneKit code, you can set up and apply the technique like this:

```
let technique = SCNTechnique(dictionary: [
    "passes": ["drawLowResStuff":
                  ["draw": "DRAW_SCENE",
                   // only draw nodes that are in this category
                   "includeCategoryMask": 2,
                   "colorStates": ["clear": true, "clearColor": "0.0"],
                   "outputs": ["color": "lowResStuff"]],
               "drawScene":
                  ["draw": "DRAW_SCENE",
                   // don’t draw nodes that are in the low-res-stuff category
                   "excludeCategoryMask": 2,
                   "colorStates": ["clear": true, "clearColor": "sceneBackground"],
                   "outputs": ["color": "COLOR"]],
               "composite":
                  ["draw": "DRAW_QUAD",
                   "metalVertexShader": "quadVertex",
                   "metalFragmentShader": "compositeFragment",
                   // don’t clear what’s currently there (the rest of the scene)
                   "colorStates": ["clear": false],
                   // use alpha blending
                   "blendStates": ["enable": true, "colorSrc": "srcAlpha", "colorDst": "oneMinusSrcAlpha"],
                   // supply the lowResStuff render target to the fragment shader
                   "inputs": ["compositeInput": "lowResStuff"],
                   // draw into the main color render target
                   "outputs": ["color": "COLOR"]]
    ],
    "sequence": ["drawLowResStuff", "drawScene", "composite"],
    "targets": ["lowResStuff": ["type": "color", "scaleFactor": 0.5]]
])

// mark the plane node as belonging to the category of stuff that gets drawn in the low-res pass
myPlaneNode.categoryBitMask = 2

// apply the technique to the scene view
mySceneView.technique = technique
```

With a test scene consisting of two spheres with the same texture, and the `scaleFactor` set to 0.25 instead of 0.5 to exaggerate the effect, the result looks like this.

[image: example screenshot of the result, showing two spheres using the same texture, one visibly rendered at a lower resolution]

If you’d prefer sharp pixelation instead of the blurrier resizing depicted above, change `filter::linear` to `filter::nearest` in the Metal code. Also, note that the low-res content being composited in is not taking into account the depth buffer, so if your plane is supposed to appear “behind” other objects then you’ll have to do some more work in the compositing function to fix that.

Comment: Thanks for the elaborate answer. What left me wondering is "the low-res content being composited in is not taking into account the depth buffer". I've got lots of objects that almost randomly need to go behind the shader's plane and in front of it. How hard do you think would it be to accommodate for this depth buffer complication?

Comment: It depends—there’s a similar approach that might work better in that case. What is the expensive shader on the plane like? Is it view-dependent, lighting-dependent, any of that?

Comment: Other than a few float inputs, it's not dependent on anything that's going on in the scene.

Comment: Okay; I’ll write up the alternative in a separate answer.

Comment: Probably not needed. Seems like I managed to solve it by placing a downscaled shader plane into a SpriteKit's `SK3DNode`, then placing that `SK3DNode` inside a SpriteKit scene as a SceneKit's `SKScene`, and then using that `SKScene` as the diffuse contents of an upscaled plane inside the root SceneKit Scene. I may post my own answer bit later. Thanks again.

Comment: Added a remark to my answer about some strange behavior with the scaling factor, maybe you could shed some light on it.